# PHP OOP Cannot set private properties

Tags: php, oop, setter

I have a class UserFavorite that extends User.
When i create new object with the class constructor setters cannot set properties.

Constructor:

```
public function __construct($username, $tabId, $favName, $favUrl = null, $favPosition = null, $favComment = null) {
    parent::__construct($username);
    $this->tabId = $this->setTabId($tabId);
    $this->favName = $this->setFavName($favName);
    $this->favUrl = $this->setFavUrl($favUrl);
    $this->favPosition = $this->setFavPosition($favPosition);
    if ($favComment) {
        $this->favComment = $this->setFavComment($favComment); 
    }
}
```

Setter:

```
public function setFavUrl($favUrl) {
        $url = filter_var($favUrl, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
        if (!$url) {
            echo $this->showError(...);
            exit;
        }
        echo $url; // THIS LOGS THE URL
        $this->favUrl = $url;
    }
```

I creatirng new instance `$fav = new UserFavorite($user->getUsername(), 1, 'favorite', 'http://abv.bg', 5, 'mamatisiebalo' );`

And when i print `$fav` i receive :

```
favorite<pre>UserFavorite Object
(
    [favName:UserFavorite:private] => 
    [tabId:UserFavorite:private] => 
    [favUrl:UserFavorite:private] => 
    [favPosition:UserFavorite:private] => 
    [favComment:UserFavorite:private] => 
    [_favId:UserFavorite:private] => 
    [username:protected] => myUserName
    [_userId:protected] => 1
)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If those properties are private properties in the `User` class, then you can't access them from the `UserFavourites` class.... that's what `private` means

Comment: `$this->tabId = $this->setTabId($tabId);` Why are you setting it manually and calling a setter? It should be either `$this->setTabId($tabId);` OR `$this->tabId = $tabId;`

Comment: +1 to what Mark Baker said.  If you are extending the class and want access to parent variables use `protected` instead of `private`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting `$this->favUrl` in the setter function, then overwritting it by assigning the result of the setter function to the same variable.

If you change

```
$this->favUrl = $this->setFavUrl($favUrl);
```

To

```
$this->setFavUrl($favUrl);
```

You should be OK.